# Overlapping UIControls in a View

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uicontrol

Im creating a custom control which consist of two layers in a donut shape. The middle is a button, while the donut part is a rotation wheel.

I have created the two parts as two individual UIControls with there own seperate images.

My problem right now is that the `Second Control` is overriding my `First Control`.

Is there a programmatically way to overlap the positions?

Storyboard screenshot:

[image]

Please focus on the particular view called `buttonView`. `Rotary knob` is the donut and `Button` is the middle button.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your donut part is bigger than your middle part, right?  If so I think you should be able to use the [hitTest:WithEvent:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/hitTest%3awithEvent%3a) function to distinguish the two.  Your middle section needs to be below your outer section in the hierarchy though.  hitTest will return the deepest view in the hierarchy that was touched.

**EDIT** As per the extended comments, the problem was that they were reversed in the XIB.  Switch them around and your mid-section will appear on top.

Comment: Yes the hole in the donut is the second control. I will dig into `hitTest:WithEvent`. Another thing i just experienced was that my control responses to the entire rectangel, which can be a problem hence my control is circular. But i assume this is not possible to solve?

Comment: @JavaCake It is possible, but you will need to do the calculations yourself.  You can then override the function pointInside:withEvent: with your calculation.

Comment: My middle section is on the top in the hierarchy.

Comment: i see that now, but it will become a painfull process considering i have to repeat same thing with my middle control. I will see if there is a different way to manage the middle button.

Comment: @JavaCake Can't you move the middle button underneath the outer one?

Comment: I could if i added transparancy to the donut itself, which should make the middle visible. But then i need to handle the touch with hitTest? Seems like a silly step if i could make the middle as the upper part.

Comment: @JavaCake Oh, then I misunderstood.  I thought that was how it was to begin with.

Comment: but i dont understand why my `bottom control` keeps jumping on the top?

Comment: @JavaCake Show in your question how they are added (or indicate that they are loaded from a XIB file)

Comment: I have just added a screenshot.

Comment: @JavaCake The screenshot shows your buttons backwards...(the items closest to the bottom are the furthest forward in the view hierarchy)

Answer (score 0):

In the view that contains them both, just call `[self bringSubviewToFront:firstLayer]`.

Comment: I have corrected an error in my notation. The problem are not the views, but the overlapping of the controls. Sorry.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Are the views the same size?  Why not just make the inner control smaller and bring it to the font?